# Dynamic addition of different node vis.js

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

is there an example of a network with dynamic addition of different nodes? For the user to select the type of the added node in the editor.
I want to know if viz.js suited for my task.

Do not judge, I am just starting to study JS.

Comment: do you have an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: @Nina Scholz like here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tFTGBu1R7W4dTqcAJcOgiQ1EsYGQ0uQi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NinaScholz, or like here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kX8cspBnOYJrAW4-BifWZiTexx6cQAeH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i don't get any information from the links, you provided.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I want to be able to select the type of node to be added. For example, after clicking on the "Add Node" button, the user could select the type of node - circle, triangle or star. 

Can this be done using vis.js? [Here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/version_migration/5.4.1_to_6.0.0/manipulationEditEdgeNoDrag.html) you can add only one type of node.